# Angular HTML attribute boolean not updating first time

Tags: angular

I have a button that I'd like to disable when a variable in my component.ts file is null, undefined, or 0. The button starts out disabled, as it should, and becomes enabled when it should, but does not go back to being disabled afterwards.

The button itself:

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="clearTableSort()" 
   label="Clear Sort" [disabled]="!sortOrder" 
   class="ui-button-secondary">
</button>
```

The function controlling `sortOrder`:

```
clearTableSort() {
  this.sortOrder = 0
  this.sortField = '_score'
}
```

There is another function that alters `sortOrder` to set it to 1 or -1 (ascending or descending). When the table is sorted the button enables, but when the clear sort button gets clicked, it does not disable until it is clicked twice.

Comment: I know this shouldn't make any difference, but could you try `[disabled]="sortOrder === 0"` just to see if it works correctly?

Comment: Are you using primeng ui library for angular??? i said for the pButton tag, if that is the case your event is (onClick) not (click)   . https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/button

Comment: @will-alexander Checking for equality to 0 has the same effect :(.
@crying-freeman I am using primeng, but only `<p-button>` requires `onClick` instead of click.

Comment: try `[disabled]="sortOrder == null || sortOrder === 0"`, also add `{{sortOrder | json}}` to your html to make sure your value is changed

Comment: What code you have written When the table is sorted?

Comment: Can you maybe reproduce it in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking at a different property that gets edited at the same time. I am now doing `[disabled]="sortField === '_score'"`. I'm still not sure why exactly this made it work though.

Answer (score 0):

!sortOrder  will give true only if: 1. sortOrder is false or 2. sortOrder is null. When sortOrder is 0 it contains something so then !sortOrder will be false